# how to keep a cloud function running until an event occurs?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

My google cloud function uses a weather api to return the weather in any input location. I am currently using an http trigger. Instead of calling the http trigger manually to check if the data is less than 0°C, how can I make the cloud function notify me whenever the weather drops below that threshold?

Comment: You could create a `Cloud Scheduler` (https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart?_ga=2.260367821.-1520050418.1606950773) to trigger your cloud function

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions are for relatively short-lived processes that are spun up in response to a supported event that occurs. Unless you weather API is a supported Cloud Functions event type, there is no way to use Cloud Functions to listen on the API until the temperature drops below zero.

The closest you *can* get is to [run a Cloud Function periodically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) or [use a Cloud Scheduler task](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) to periodically trigger a Cloud Function you write that then calls the weather API, checks the temperature, and performs whatever logic you want in response. And if the weather API supports calling web hooks on temperature changes, you could also [use those web hooks to call into Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/webhooks#vs).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am still a little confused about two things. First, how can I implement user input, users have the choice to request different weather locations? Second, How can I trigger the periodic function. I only want to begin running the function when a user requests the data?

Comment: You can easily start a function upon a user request, either though [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), through [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) or by triggering through one of the other event types. But those functions can run no longer than 9 minutes.

Comment: I'm really wondering about the architecture here though. Your first question should be: does the weather API have a way to subscribe to updates, or does it follow the (much more common) request/response model? If the latter, why don't you call the API repeatedly directly from the client? If that is because of security: a common approach is to wrap the calls to the weather API in Cloud Functions, and then poll *those* repeatedly from your clients.

Comment: I have thought of making the API calls from the client, I was reluctant to doing it that way because I was trying to avoid the case where the user kills the application from running in the background. In that case, I will not be able to send a notification. Also, I was trying to avoid running things periodically on the client's side to reduce cpu and ram usage.